# Perform partial string match in ElasticSearch (Kibana)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have the following property name in Kibana

```
{
    "source": {
        "type": "id",
        "id": "src_gn266o4vf5nevifl663fx3oggy"
    },
    "amount": 1234,
    "currency": "AED",
    "capture": true
}
```

How could I get all the results of **type: id** and **id** that starts with **src_** ?

The following regex doesn't work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "e.Properties.RequestBody": {
        "query": "'source''type''id''id''src_*'",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [Wildcard Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)? You can just do `src_*`

Comment: Its a perfect use case of prefix queries as he just needs to fetch all the docs, starting with `src_` prefix, please check my answer for detailed explanation and feel free to comment if more info required.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the wildcard query:

```
GET index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "source.id": {
        "value": "src_*"
      }
    }
  }
{
```

Answer (score 1):

While other answers and the similar comment will bring the expected search results, but they are not very performant and cause severe performance issues on large Elasticsearch cluster and later on would be difficult to troubleshoot them.

**Your use case is perfect for [prefix querie](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html)s and that's why Elasticsearch has this special type of query** and below is the example, which shows how its returns you expected example (for simplicity, having just 1 field `id`):

### Index def

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
               "type": "text"
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

### Index sample docs

```
{
  "id" : "src_opster"
}

{
  "id" : "dest_opster"
}

{
  "id" : "src_1234"
}

{
  "id" : "src_gn266o4vf5nevifl663fx3oggy"
}
```

### Search query

```
{
    "query": {
        "prefix": {
            "id": { --> change it to `source.id` in your case
                "value": "src_"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Search result

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "so_regex",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "src_gn266o4vf5nevifl663fx3oggy"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "so_regex",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "src_1234"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "so_regex",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "id": "src_opster"
        }
      }
    ]
```